# How to upload a file as a binary in request body of REST API using restassured Java?

Tags: java, api, rest, binary, rest-assured

```
curl command for my request looks like below:
curl --location --request PUT '<endpoint URI>' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/octet-stream' \
--data-binary '@/<file location>'
```

How can I pass the file as binary using restassured in Java?

Answer (score 1):

Found by myself as usual ;)

High Level Java code:

```
given()
                .relaxedHTTPSValidation()
                .header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename", file)
                .body(file)
```

Output:

```
Request method: <HTTP METHOD>
Request URI:    <endpoint URI>
Proxy:          <none>
Request params: <none>
Query params:   <none>
Form params:    <none>
Path params:    <none>
Headers:        Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="<absolute filepath>"         
                Accept=*/*
                Content-Type=text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1
Cookies:        <none>
Multiparts:     <none>
Body:
<relative filePath>
net.serenitybdd.rest.decorators.request.RequestSpecificationDecorated reportQuery
INFO: No BaseStepListener, PUT  not registered.

Date: Thu, 12 Aug 2021 14:48:26 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Server: Kestrel
Cache-Control: no-store
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Location: 
Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'none'
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload
Response: <RESPONSE>
```