# How can I send PUT request with image file through java code?

Tags: java, put, rest-assured

I tried many ways but what I need is:

**Headers:**

```
x-type : internal
Content-Type : application/octet-stream
x-ms-blob-type : BlockBlob
```

Body should be image file (works in postman) as binary (like postman)
and then the request sent it to blob storage.

I never succeed, Got all kind of errors.

```
RestAssured.baseURI = "https://mediasa.blob.core.windows.net";
    RequestSpecification request = RestAssured.given().contentType(ContentType.JSON);
    request.header("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
    request.header("x-ms-blob-type", "BlockBlob");
    request.header("x-type", "internal");
    request.body(convertImageToBinary("image.jpeg"));
    Response response = request.given().filter(new RequestLoggingFilter(requestCapture)).put(sas);
```

curl from postman:

```
curl --location --request PUT 'https://mediasaqa.blob.core.windows.net/3r4y3yr483yr4843r' \
--header 'x-type: internal' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/octet-stream' \
--header 'x-ms-blob-type: BlockBlob' \
--data-binary '@/Q:New Docs/ARM2).jpg'
```

Unirest from Postman:

HttpResponse response =

```
Unirest.put("https://qa.blob.core.windows.net/output_page1.jpeg?sv=2020-06rcw&sigD")
  .header("x-type", "internal")
  .header("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream")
  .header("x-ms-blob-type", "BlockBlob")
  .body("<file contents here>")
  .asString();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better if you can post your setup in postman

Try this

```
given().log().all()
       .header("x-ms-blob-type", "BlockBlob")
       .header("x-type", "internal")
       .contentType(ContentType.BINARY)
       .body(file)
       .when()
       .post("https://postman-echo.com/post")
       .then().log().all();
```

Some link seems helpful

https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/issues/964

[How to upload a file as a binary in request body of REST API using restassured Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68755563/how-to-upload-a-file-as-a-binary-in-request-body-of-rest-api-using-restassured-j)

https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/blob/master/examples/rest-assured-itest-java/src/test/java/io/restassured/itest/java/FileUploadingITest.java

Comment: Getting that now:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot serialize because cannot determine how to serialize content-type application/octet-stream

Comment: Please update the postman setting that works for you.

Comment: @Eyal pls provide more information, especially postman settings, I can base on this to make the same request in rest-assured.

Comment: Added to the main post

Comment: Doesn't work - getting 403, same pc success with postman

Comment: 403 means Authorization failed, not relate to content of file.

Comment: I have used Unirest and it is working, I updated the code in the Post - Please tell me why restassured doesn't works ?
restassured gets 403 and unirest gets 201

Comment: I've updated the answer based on example here https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/blob/4eeb3d82b1d4672787b57ca45167a63085c8c1f1/examples/rest-assured-itest-java/src/test/java/io/restassured/itest/java/FileUploadingITest.java#L89

Comment: not helping, I get 403:
HTTP/1.1 403 Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature. 403

Comment: Your url is private, I can’t troubleshoot from my side. I’ve tried my code in other upload binary api and it worked. Did you include authentication info along with the request?